# insert a row after a specified row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have seen similar examples but have not seen exactly what I am looking for.
I have created a scheduling system based on the time of day.
This means I have 24 rows.
The first td of each row has a button with the class "go".
I am trying to create a snippet that... when an individual button is clicked on a specific row that row is cloned and inserted on the next line of the table.
 I have accomplished this with a single button and have used the insertAfter object.
 I assume I have to do something with the .each but am not very familiar with it.
This is an example of an attempt.
Note that in this case I used an id of go and I created a hidden tr with the id to_be_cloned and inserted it after row 1.
I need to be able to insert the row after any other row upon clicking that rows button. (if that makes any sense)

```
$("#go").click(function() { 
    $("#to_be_cloned").clone().show().attr('id','').insertAfter("#1");
})
```

Comment: please please please, do not have your DOM IDs start (or just be) a number.

Comment: Can you please share your HTML - or at least an example, perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: will do Neal. Just in testing now. I am used to working with forms so the whole table structure is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class to bind the event to the button instead of an id.
It is not valid if you have duplicate ID's also, an ID can not start with a numeric value.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="button" class="insertButton" value="Go"/></td>
      <td>Hello World</td>
   </tr>
</table>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.insertButton').live('click', function(){
       var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
       $(this).closest('table').append(row);
   });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/Q6cJz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Make all rows have the same class. then you can try this:

```
$(".rowClass .go").live('click', function() {  //clicked go in this row
    var row = $(this).parents(".rowClass");
    row.clone().show().insertAfter(row);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/E4K39/

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
$(".go").live('click', function() { 
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.clone().insertAfter($tr);
});
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="go">Go</a></td>
        <td>somethign</td>
        <td>another 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="go">Go</a></td>
        <td>somethign</td>
        <td>another 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="go">Go</a></td>
        <td>somethign</td>
        <td>another 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsfddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jYMmu/4/

Comment: It's to match example provided by OP. Changed to class.

Comment: Why would you perpetuate incorrect practices, it's wrong and you should point that out in the answer.